# Want to read content from two text files then compare and write to another text file with java

Tags: java

I have text files.

- album.txt
- new_album.txt

Each text files contains some folder name.

For example,

album.txt contains

> @Event1
>
> @Event2
>
> @Event3

and new_album.txt contains

> @Event1(update20-05-2015)
>
> @Event2(update03-03-2016)
>
> @Event3(update15-08-2016)
>
> @Event4(update30-07-2017)

I want to compare similar folder name from album.txt with new_album.txt line by line, then put folder name that similar from album.txt to similar.txt and put folder name that not match to not_match.txt .

Output in similar.txt

> @Event1
>
> @Event2
>
> @Event3

Output in not_match.txt

> @Event4(update30-07-2017)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareFileName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br1 = null;
        BufferedReader br2 = null;
        String sCurrentLine;
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("album.txt"));
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("new_album.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            list1.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
        while ((sCurrentLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            list2.add(sCurrentLine);
        }
//This part is my problem
            List <String> list_similar = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List <String> list_not_match = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            for (String string : list1) {
               if(string.matches("list2")){ //I don't know how to compare similar folder name from list2 with list1.
                   list_similar.add(string);
               }else{list_not_match.add(string)}
           }
```

//This part is the part I use for add string to text file but it not complete I want to write string from list_similar to similar.text and list_not_match to not_match.txt

```
        file = new File("similar.txt"); 
        fileName = "similar.txt"; 
        str = file.list();

    try{
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        for(String string:str){
            outputStream.println(string);
        }
        outputStream.close(); 
        System.out.println("get name complete");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done.");
        }
```

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: Go for scripting languages for thoses kind of things. (bash, python ...)

Comment: So where are you stuck?  Are you asking how to read a text file in Java?  How to compare strings in Java?  How to write output in Java?  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Application (main method)

```
    public class Application {
    
        public static void main(String... aArgs) throws IOException {
    
            InputParser firstListInputParser = new InputParser(new File(/**"Your path to /album.txt"*/));
            firstListInputParser.processLineByLine();
            List<String> firstList = firstListInputParser.getListWithParsedFolderNames();
            firstListInputParser.printMap();
    
            InputParser secondListInputParser = new InputParser(new File(/**"Your path to /new_album.txt"*/));
            secondListInputParser.processLineByLine();
            List<String> secondList = secondListInputParser.getListWithParsedFolderNames();
            secondListInputParser.printMap();
    
            // Create the list with common value and write it to the file
            List<String> listWithCommonValues = new ArrayList<String>(firstList);
            listWithCommonValues.retainAll(secondList);
    
            Path fileCommon = Paths.get(/**"Your path to /similar.txt"*/);
            Files.write(fileCommon, listWithCommonValues, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    
            // Create the list with different values and write it to the file
            List<String> listWithAllValues = new ArrayList<String>(firstList);
            listWithAllValues.addAll(secondList);
            //remove the common values from the list with all values
            listWithAllValues.removeAll(listWithCommonValues);
    
            Path fileDistincts = Paths.get(/**"Your path to /not_match.txt"*/);
            Files.write(fileDistincts, listWithAllValues, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    
    
        }
    
        private static void log(Object aObject){
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(aObject));
        }
    }
```

#### Inputparser

```
     /**
         * Assumes UTF-8 encoding
         */
        public class InputParser {
        
            //create a list to hold the values
            List<String> listWithParsedFolderNames = new ArrayList<>();
        
        
            //private final Path fFilePath;
            private final File file;
            private final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        
            /**
             Constructor.
             @param aFileName full name of an existing, readable file.
             */
            public InputParser(File aFileName){
                //fFilePath = Paths.get(aFileName);
               file = aFileName;
            }
        
            /**
             * Processes each line and calls {@link #processLine(String)}}.
             */
            public final void processLineByLine() throws IOException {
                try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file, ENCODING.name())){
                    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
                        processLine(fileScanner.nextLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        
            /**
             Overridable method for processing lines in different ways.
             *Parses the line and cuts away the part after '(update'
             * Ex1: input line: @Event1(update20-05-2015)
             * Ex1: output    : @Event1
             *
             * Ex2: input line: @Event2
             * Ex2: output    : @Event2
             */
            protected void processLine(String aLine){
        
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(aLine);
        
                    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        String name = scanner.next();
                        String finalName = name.split("\\(update")[0];
        
                        //stores the values in the list
                        listWithParsedFolderNames.add(finalName);
        
                    } else {
                        log("Empty or invalid line. Unable to process.");
                    }
        
            }
        
            /**
             * Prints the content of the listWlistWithParsedFolderNames
             */
            public void printMap() {
                Iterator it = listWithParsedFolderNames.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    log("The prsed value is: " + it.next());
                }
            }
        
            /**
             * @return the list with values
             */
            public List<String > getListWithParsedFolderNames() {
                return this.listWithParsedFolderNames;
            }
        
        
            private static void log(Object aObject){
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(aObject));
            }
        
        }
```

In the similar.txt it will print:

```
@Event1
@Event2
@Event3
```

In the not_match.txt it will print:

```
@Event4
```

If you want it to print @Event4(update30-07-2017) into the not_match class you will have to change the list to a key value map that has the parsed input @Event4 as key and the full line @Event4(update30-07-2017) as value. After comparing the keys of the map you can write the values into your file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read something from files, you can use these streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("path\\to\\your\\file.txt"))); //or any format
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path\\to\\your\\second\\file.txt")));
    //read one line from your file
    String line = reader.readLine();
    //write something to your file
    writer.write(line);
}
```

If you want to read folder names you can use this.

```
File f = f = new File("path\\to\\your\\folder\\with\\files");

File[] files = f.listFiles();

for(File currentFile : files) {
    System.out.println(currentFile.getName());
}
```

If you want to create new files or folders, you can use this.

```
File f = f = new File("path\\to\\your\\folder\\with\\files");
f.mkdir();
//or
f.mkdirs();
//or if you have File f = new File("myTextFile.txt"); then you can create file using this:
f.createNewFile();
```